# getListView is missing

Tags: android

I have created a **ListView** to list all the activities but when I wanna call the method, I can't find **getListView**

My activity_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my **MainActivity.java** seems like there's an error with

> getListView

method, I've no idea why

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you're missing a semi-colon?

Comment: Yea sure, it's not about the semicolon...

Comment: No,.. cus I've followed every steps to create a list view... but then I didn't find getListView

Comment: Please provide your entire MainActivity.

Comment: @BenScmidth There is nothing to do with a list view.You need MainActivity extends from ListActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activity must inherit from a `ListActivity`. Your class should start with

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ListActivity {

   ...

}
```

Then you can use the method

```
getListView()
```

This is the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

**Second solution**

If you use a fragment, then you can access your `ListView` by using

```
ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_listView);
```

The `rootView` is the view you get in your `onCreateView` Method of the Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Right, that's right... but my MainActivity doesn't extend ListView since I have just created a new Blank Fragment to create a list of activities...

Comment: So you just want to access your listview, defined in xml, in the fragment?

Comment: Yes mate to access, I think this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm is right, but I didn't get as what's the result in it..

Comment: Can you give me the code of the fragment where you want the ListView to be displayed in?

Comment: Then please accept it as the correct answer, so other users are helped too.

Comment: I've tried all the answers and another answers are work as well... so I'm sorry to just accept one answer...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getListView()` when working with `ListActivity` not the usual `Activity`. In your code you got it wrong and made the `ListView` with **id** "a special identifier to the view" ListActivity, so to access it in your code you simply

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListActivity);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Try using `(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListActivity)` instead of getListView()

Comment: make sure you have imported the ListView class

`import android.widget.ListView;`

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ListView in the fragment you can use:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

But if you want to use getListView directly you must call the ListView's id as

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend `ListActivity` because 1) You are wanting to use Fragments and 2) there isn't a method `setSupportActionBar` for the `ListActivity` class...

Anyways... in your question

> My activity_fragment.xml
>
> `<!-- XML code -->`

You can't use `findViewById` to get that `ListView` within the `Activity` class because your `ListView` isn't within `activity_main.xml`.

You have to do it from within the Fragment.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView yourListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);

        this.yourListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // adapter stuff...

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: That helps mate, thanks a lot... Since I got the same with another answer, I can just accept any of yours...one only... mm

Comment: You still need to figure out how to display the Fragment within the activity, though.

Comment: You may just want to read [Adding a Fragment to an Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)

Answer (score 1):

also note that you dont pass your ListView to the adapter but you pass the adapter to the ListView

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListActivity);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```